# Black background after resizing image in php using gd

Tags: php, gd

I use the below code to resize images (jpg, png, gif). The code is working perfectly. But the problem is after resizing the images, all transparent images (both png and gif) have a black background.

How can I maintain the transparency so that resized images will have not have black background?

```
 $target = 'uploads/'.$newname;

 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);;

 $filename=$newname;
 if($ext=='jpg'||$ext=='jpeg') {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploads/'.$filename);
    } else if ($ext=='gif') {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif('uploads/'.$filename);
    } else if ($ext=='png') {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng('uploads/'.$filename);
    }
    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);
    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);
    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,400,300,$ox,$oy);
     imagejpeg($nm,  'thumbnails/' . $filename);
```

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688954/how-to-replace-black-background-with-white-when-resizing-converting-png-images-w?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

> [imagesavealpha()](http://php.net/ImageSaveAlpha) sets the flag to attempt to save full alpha channel
>   information (as opposed to single-color transparency) when saving PNG
>   images.
>
> You have to unset alphablending (imagealphablending($im, false)), to
>   use it.

Try adding

```
imagealphablending( $nm, FALSE );
imagesavealpha( $nm, TRUE );
```

Here:

```
.
.
$nm = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);
imagealphablending( $nm, FALSE );
imagesavealpha( $nm, TRUE );
.
.
```

Also consider using [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled) instead of [imagecopyresized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php).

> [imagecopyresampled()](http://www.php.net/imagecopyresampled) smoothly interpolates pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity.

Use `imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,400,300,$ox,$oy);`

Instead of
    `imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,400,300,$ox,$oy);`

Comment: Sorry it worked for png images. But not working for gif. Though it worked for png, images obtained are off poor clarity... colors are spread like that. Cannot be used. Instead of transparency is there any way to give white background??

Comment: try using `imagecopyresampled` instead of `imagecopyresized`

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar troubles where a black background still appeared when using:

```
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
```

I found the below combination to be successful though:

```
imagecolortransparent($image, imagecolorallocate($thumbnail, 0, 0, 0));
imagealphablending($image, false);
```