# Save image from Canvas using PHP without black background

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

I have a project where I need to save the image from a user drawn canvas using php. The problem is that the file saved always has a black background when I want the default to be white or transparent.

I have tried drawing a white fill in to the canvas but sketch.js wipes this away when interactions are made in the canvas.

JS

```
function saveImage(){
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //do something with the response
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","upload.php",true);
    var oldCanvas = document.getElementById('colors_sketch').toDataURL("image/png");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = oldCanvas;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/upload")
    xmlhttp.send(oldCanvas);
}
```

PHP

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]);

imagepng($im, 'filename.png');
```

I have modified it to this as suggested but cannot seem to save

```
$filePath = '($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])';  
$savePath = 'filename.png';  //full path to saved png, including filename and extension
$colorRgb = array('red' => 255, 'green' => 0, 'blue' => 0);  //background color

$img = @imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$width  = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);


$backgroundImg = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($backgroundImg, $colorRgb['red'], $colorRgb['green'],                 $colorRgb['blue']);
imagefill($backgroundImg, 0, 0, $color);


imagecopy($backgroundImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);


imagepng($backgroundImg, $savePath, 0);
```

Comment: Have you tried saving as a gif or a png? jpegs can't handle transparency. Try `imagepng($im, 'filename.png');`. Also note that `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` should be avoided, as should `$GLOBALS` - the preferred method for fetching the raw post data into a string would be `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Yeah I did originally. This doesn't work. Sorry I didn't post the png version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add background in **PHP** not in Canvas.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8447558/739897) solution. Main key is to create image with background:

```
$backgroundImg = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($backgroundImg, $colorRgb['red'], $colorRgb['green'], $colorRgb['blue']);
imagefill($backgroundImg, 0, 0, $color);
```

And copy your image on it:

```
imagecopy($backgroundImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

Comment: Apologies I am very new to php. I have edited it in the manner described in edit above

Comment: `$filePath = '($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])'; ` Try to remove brackets `$filePath = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]; `

Comment: Brackets and quotes. Updated my comment above.

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't save the png at all at the moment (with brackets or without)

Comment: +1 this does seem to be the answer, it works for me. @user2307186 try [this code](http://codepad.org/N8XSW8tl).

Comment: Thank you so much!
Working perfectly

Comment: Is there any chance you can help me with my other post, being trying other solutions all day and can't seem to get it functioning.

Comment: @user2307186 give link to question.